# MacBook shutting down randomly (about every 5 minutes)

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown

The shutdown is now almost regular. It happens every few minutes.
It does not happen in safe boot mode, but in that case, Chromium browsers do not work, and startup takes over 5 minutes. If I then close the macbook, it freezes shortly after reopening.
Very unpractical...

---

This is a typical log file

2022-02-26 16:51:32.774836+0100 0x1be      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOHIDFamily) HID: Legacy shim 2
2022-02-26 16:51:32.775144+0100 0x14a      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleUSBMultitouch) AppleUSBMultitouchDriver::checkStatus - received Status Packet, Payload 2: device was reinitialized
2022-02-26 16:51:33.153173+0100 0x7d       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOTimeSyncFamily) IOTimeSyncClockManager::delayedClockIDLookup registered service
2022-02-26 16:51:51.356665+0100 0x195      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3327: scan took 18.923222 s, trims took 2.832145 s
2022-02-26 16:51:51.356681+0100 0x195      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3335: 130197229 blocks free in

---

And another

---

2022-02-26 17:02:59.776576+0100 0xdb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOBluetoothUSBDFU) IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
2022-02-26 17:02:59.776589+0100 0xdb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOBluetoothUSBDFU) IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8289 FirmwareVersion - 0x0150
2022-02-26 17:02:59.779259+0100 0x1be      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport) **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x3000 ****
2022-02-26 17:02:59.779269+0100 0x1be      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport) **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed (matched on Device) -- 0x3000 ****
2022-02-26 17:03:00.164255+0100 0xdb       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (IOTimeSyncFamily) IOTimeSyncClockManager::delayedClockIDLookup registered service
2022-02-26 17:03:18.669041+0100 0x197      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3327: scan took 19.220222 s, trims took 2.831143 s
2022-02-26 17:03:18.669056+0100 0x197      Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (apfs) spaceman_trim_free_blocks:3335: 130172667 blocks free in 646130 extents

---

My MacBook Pro (2014, Intel Chip) with macOS 10.14.6 shuts down randomly, with no warning.
This is happening since a few days. (I have the laptop since several years.) Shutdown is every 4 to 10 minutes.
Independent of battery state. Needs restart afterwards. Also happens with power cord.
Also "Calendar" was always opening at start-up, even though it was not in the
login queue. I zipped it away.

It must be a SW problem, as it does NOT happen in "safe boot" mode
(started by pushing "shift" just after power on.)
Recently uploaded SW: only Filezilla, Zoom, Avira, Malwarebytes, and browsers.

2 anti-virus programs found nothing.
I deleted everything form the login queue (System Preferences Users & Groups). No effect.
I reset NVRAM with alt-command-P-R. No change.
I restarted with ctrl-alt-shift. No change.

Cleaned the keyboard.

What else can I do?
Can one search the console somehow?

---

Two graphics cards:

```
Intel Iris Pro:

  Chipset Model:    Intel Iris Pro
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
  Vendor:   Intel
  Device ID:    0x0d26
  Revision ID:  0x0008
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.8 [3.2.8]

NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M:

  Chipset Model:    NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  PCIe
  PCIe Lane Width:  x8
  VRAM (Total): 2 GB
  Vendor:   NVIDIA (0x10de)
  Device ID:    0x0fe9
  Revision ID:  0x00a2
  ROM Revision: 3776
  Automatic Graphics Switching: Supported
  gMux Version: 4.0.8 [3.2.8]
```

---

Today, there was, the first time, a full freeze of the laptop. (NO way to move the pointer; needed 10 sec hard shutdown.)

---

The command `pmset -g log | grep ShutdownCause` gives nothing as answer.

---

Since a few hours, the white bar that increases under the Apple logo during startup is orange, not white, during most of the 15s it takes for startup.

---

In systemlog it says

```
Feb 22 07:41:19 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.opendirectoryd): Unknown key for Boolean: BeginTransactionAtShutdown
Feb 22 07:41:19 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.cups.cupsd): Service has increased maximum shutdown time to 65 seconds. This will create a poor experience for the user.
Feb 22 07:50:03 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.opendirectoryd): Unknown key for Boolean: BeginTransactionAtShutdown
Feb 22 07:50:03 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.cups.cupsd): Service has increased maximum shutdown time to 65 seconds. This will create a poor experience for the user.
Feb 22 08:05:21 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.opendirectoryd): Unknown key for Boolean: BeginTransactionAtShutdown
Feb 22 08:05:21 localhost com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (org.cups.cupsd): Service has increased maximum shutdown time to 65 seconds. This will create a poor experience for the user.
```

---

In safe boot mode, almost all browsers display erratically. This could confirm a problem with the graphics card.

---

`cd /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` and `ls` yields:

```
AdobeAcrobat_2022-02-06-091445_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
AdobeAcrobat_2022-02-06-091528_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.hang
AdobeAcrobat_2022-02-06-093518_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
AdobeAcrobat_2022-02-06-093521_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.hang
Analytics_2022-01-27-070543_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-01-31-030615_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-02-070840_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-03-013400_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-04-050313_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-05-045755_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-06-053025_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-07-035014_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-09-041515_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-10-041526_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-12-010021_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-13-063048_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-15-044539_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-16-014253_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-18-021845_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-19-075021_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-20-010739_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-21-060249_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-22-030007_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Analytics_2022-02-23-014137_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.core_analytics
Distiller_2022-01-26-155912_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-22-224242_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-25-222110_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-25-225602_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-26-210800_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-28-080223_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-28-085321_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-01-31-222559_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-01-171331_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-04-143527_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-18-071737_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-18-090746_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-18-115441_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Google Chrome Helper (Renderer)_2022-02-20-122743_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
Mail_2022-02-17-232137_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
WindowServer_2022-02-18-102940_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
WindowServer_2022-02-20-193707_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
backupd_2022-02-18-201629_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
bnepd_2022-01-23-115537_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-01-23-115756_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-01-28-012229_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-01-28-172543_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-01-31-230510_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-03-145518_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-04-073103_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-07-164152_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-09-073931_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-10-123507_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-10-233349_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-12-224122_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-13-063122_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-16-092002_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-16-175655_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-17-071736_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-18-054250_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
bnepd_2022-02-18-054555_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.crash
com.apple.MediaLibraryService_2022-02-15-164313_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
firefox_2022-01-28-040816_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
firefox_2022-02-13-065234_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
firefox_2022-02-15-081451_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
firefox_2022-02-18-040258_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
iTunes_2022-02-13-143823_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.hang
inkscape_2022-01-30-180859_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
inkscape_2022-02-03-131920_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
plugin-container_2022-02-15-080755_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
plugin-container_2022-02-18-032317_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
shutdown_stall_2022-02-18-111658_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-18-122242_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-18-122657_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-18-200328_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-105259_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-105817_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-105930_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-110025_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-110126_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-112131_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-131818_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-142711_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-174942_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-19-175146_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-061029_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-103738_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-104542_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-110548_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-174334_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
shutdown_stall_2022-02-20-232946_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.shutdownStall
signpost_reporter_2022-01-29-073901_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.cpu_resource.diag
zoom.us_2022-02-15-204350_2010MacBook-von-Nemo-3.wakeups_resource.diag
```

Comment: Is this an MBP with a discrete GPU? Safe Boot forces using the Intel GPU instead. The discrete GPUs have been a source of problems in many MBP models.

Comment: Yes, see above. But does this occur after so many years of use?

Comment: A sudden shut off is definitely some kind of hardware problem. Software doesn't do that. The GPU circuitry can fail at any point in the life. Why that should cause a power shut off, I'm not sure.

Comment: Please add the result of the following Terminal command to the end of your original question via a code block: `pmset -g log | grep ShutdownCause`

Comment: Do I need to do this in a particular directory?

Comment: @MotionMountain No

Comment: Do you see any kernel panics in `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports`? Are you by any chance using Chrome as your web browser?

Comment: I usually use Firefox. It does a shutdown in either browser.

Comment: BUt in Chrome, in "safe boot" mode, the system behaves strangely: hromium browsers do not work well: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1299429  This might be a graphics card problmem.

Comment: The next time this happens, note the exact time and date. Then upon your next reboot, let's collect logs beginning at the last 10 seconds leading up to the shutdown. Use the following command: `log show --info --debug --start "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" --end "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` where you would replace the placeholders with real numbers denoting the time range from 10 seconds before the shutdown until the first log messages after your reboot. This will likely be a lot of text, so please use a service like www.PasteBin.com to upload your log.

Comment: This is now found on www.motionmountain.net/list.txt (freeze in safe boot mode)

Comment: @MotionMountain I think you're using the wrong timestamps. Your file doesn't capture the period of time from before the shutdown through after the boot. Can you try again?

Comment: Next try: https://www.motionmountain.net/list2.txt

Comment: @pion  newest list in https://www.motionmountain.net/list2.txt

Comment: And a further one in motionmountain.net/list3.txt

Comment: The basic lines are now copied at the very top of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
2022-02-23 22:33:44.735232+0100 0xaf       Default     0x0                  0      0    kernel: (AppleSMC) Previous shutdown cause: -128
```

A shutdown cause of `-128` means that the SMC lost power before it could record a valid shutdown cause. This can happen for many reasons, but the most common reason is that there was suddenly insufficient electrical power available. This is seen frequently on systems as old as yours where the original battery has not yet been replaced. (See my answer in [Apple battery issue or something else?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/430545/apple-battery-issue-or-something-else/430559#430559)) I suspect that you are probably near 1,000 power cycles by this point. (You can check in `System Information`.)

`-128` is difficult to debug directly because there is so little diagnostic information available in these cases. One thing you could try is replacing the battery. But that would be an experiment and no guarantee that it actually targets the root cause. If you are running the latest OS with the latest firmware updates and no third party hardware attached or kernel extensions installed, you're likely looking at a hardware failure. Run [Apple Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) and then bring your machine in to an Apple authorized repair center.