# Frequent shutdowns

Tags: kernel-extensions

My MBA 2017 with Monterey 12.7 frequently just shuts-down

No messages just black screen.

Hardware test shows nothing

New Monterey install does noting

Shutdowns have no pattern, it even happens in Sleep mode

It works fine in Safe mode.

Reseting SMC/NVRAM does not help

Terminal report shows following

[image: terminal]

Console reports show nothing of interest, or I missed it

The way I read that is a "some kernel send request to AppleSMC to shut down". Makes sense since the OS can not shut down but the SMC been the power controller can.

Right now I am trying to find out witch Kernels are loaded that are not Apple, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I am trying to find out which Kernels are loaded that are not Apple, how do I do that?

#### Use the `kmutil` command

```
sudo kmutil showloaded --list-only
```

Apple's kexts begin with "com.apple", so anything that dosn't start with this prefix is a 3rd party kext.

Comment: OK, restated from Safe mode and run the `sudo kmutil showloaded --list-only` and they are all `com.apple` and for now the Mac is stable

Comment: The easiest path forward (IMO) is to do a clean reinstall.  Whenever I upgrade from one version to the next, I like to do a fresh install on a wiped drive to ensure I’m not bringing over obsolete drivers/apps.  Make sure all your data is backed up.

Answer (score -1):

A -128 shutdown is an 'unknown' hardware error code, but usually indicative of a power failure.

This might suggest that the battery needs replacing; alternatively it could be a fault with the power management circuitry itself.

I'd suggest taking it to an Apple Store, or other Apple-approved repair shop.

[Shutdown Cause -128](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/212809/shutdown-cause-128)

[MacBook shutting down randomly (about every 5 minutes)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/437327/macbook-shutting-down-randomly-about-every-5-minutes)